# What is the circle icon in Chrome's Network tab?

Tags: http, google-chrome

What is the circle icon in this request?
It's a GET request that returns a pdf.

[image]

It does it in incognito as well.

I have the following extensions installed:

- Cisco Webex Extension
- Google Docs Offline
- Docs
- Sheets
- Slides

Comment: It looks like a cog to me. Also, cogs are circles. What plugins (extensions) do you have on this profile? Do you have the same behavior  under incognito mode? Give it a try and let us know.

Comment: @bitcollision I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably a request from a service worker. They reference it as a gear. Cog/gear... What is the difference? Please don't down vote.... I know the difference....

> A service worker is a type of web worker. It's essentially a JavaScript file that runs separately from the main browser thread, intercepting network requests, caching or retrieving resources from the cache, and delivering push messages.

Reference from https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker

Check out https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/registration

 and https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers

Comment: You can see what service workers are running via chrome by putting in chrome://inspect/#service-workers in your address bar in Google Chrome.

Comment: What do you mean by "What is the difference? Please don't down vote.... I know the difference...."?

Comment: It was a poor attempt at humor.